# Drag and drop an image from UIPopoverController to UIViewController

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uipopovercontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I'm showing a UIPopoverController in a ViewController, and I want to drag one image from the popover to the ViewController.

I know that to do it, I need to use a UIGestureRecognizer, but I don't know how.  I can move the image around the popover, but I can't drag and drop it to the ViewController.

My code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveImage:)];
    [panGesture setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];    
}

- (void)moveImage:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    CGPoint newCenter = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

    if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        beginX = ball.center.x; 
        beginY = ball.center.y;
    }

    newCenter = CGPointMake(beginX + newCenter.x, beginY + newCenter.y);

    [ball setCenter:newCenter];
}
```